# Alamofire get request url parameters

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I need to create a url like "myserverbaseurl.com/category/{id}/subcategory

{id} in this url needs to be parametric and can change. The rest of the url is constant. Does Alamofire have an easy way for this or I need to do this with String?

Comment: `Moya` is build on top of `Alamofire` and it has an easy way for this

Comment: I already advanced in this project right now, but for next project Moya looks as a really good change thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Start setting your parameter in a constant and use a function to make your call, for example:

```
func myAPICall(id: String){

    let url = "myserverbaseurl.com/category/" + id + "/subcategory"

    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { (response) in 
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: I am looking for a way in Alamofire library if it is possible

Comment: I see. If you want the easiest way I think this is and I always use it that way. By reading the Alamofire doc, I don't think there is such other way, but maybe someone can find one.